# IDLE's subprocess didn't make connection

Tags: python, python-idle

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLkOW.png)

I'm currently running Mac OS X 10.12. I've allowed access for IDLE in my firewall settings and even tried turning my firewall off completely. Still, no luck getting IDLE or any of my python programs to run. I have looked for duplicate files in my python folder, no luck. I have researched the issue for a few days now with no luck. Any further tips or troubleshooting would be awesome

Comment: Unless you have a Mac-specific problem, this is a duplicate of multiple issues.  I don't know of anything not already covered.  Are you using the installer at python.org?  Did you upgrade tcl/tk as directed on https://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/?

Comment: I'm running Python downloaded from python.org, and I have upgraded tcl/tk as well